# Cordova: start specific iOS emulator image

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm developing a cross-platform mobile app using Cordova, focussing mainly on iOS in the development stage.

For my development process it would be ideal if I could start my Cordova app directly from the command line and have it load into a specified emulator. I can do this by running the following from the project root directory:

```
$cordova run --debug --emulator iOS
```

This works fine, and results in an iOS-simulator running my app in a simulated iPhone 4 Retina with iOS 7.0.3

Besides this simulated device, I would also like to test on (for instance) an iPad. I have these emulation images installed, and I can start my app in them manually in Xcode. Also, the command `list-emulator-images` (located in `project_dir/platforms/ios/cordova/lib`) gives the following output:

```
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)"
"iPhone Retina (4-inch)"
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"
"iPhone"
"iPad"
"iPad Retina"
```

However, the thing is: I can't seem to figure out how to start the emulator in anything other than the default (which appears to be the `iPhone Retina (4-inch)` emulation image). The relevant output of `cordova help` gives the following information:

```
run [--debug|--release]
    [--device|--emulator|--target=FOO]
    [PLATFORM] ............................ deploys app on specified platform devices / emulators
```

I've tried things like the following:

`cordova run --debug --emulator=iPad iOS`

And many variations thereof, but no luck. Every time it starts in the same emulator.

[The documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) for the command-line tool doesn't offer any information in this regard, and an extensive Google-search also failed to turn up anything. Am I missing something trivial? Or am I trying to do something weird? I really hope someone here has experience with this, and can provide some answers.

Thanks very much in advance!

edit: forgot to mention explicitly; I'm doing all this on a Mac. As mentioned earlier, running the app in different emulators/simulators in Xcode works fine.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

To find out what are the simulator images available you can use to list them

```
$ cordova emulate ios --list
Available iOS Virtual Devices:
    iPhone-4s, 9.3
    iPhone-5, 9.3
    iPhone-5s, 9.3
    iPhone-6, 9.3
    iPhone-6-Plus, 9.3
    iPhone-6s, 9.3
    iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.3
    iPad-2, 9.3
    iPad-Retina, 9.3
    iPad-Air, 9.3
    iPad-Air-2, 9.3
    iPad-Pro, 9.3
```

Then use one of the simulator names in the --target parameter:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-4s, 9.3"
cordova emulate ios --target="iPad-Air-2, 9.3"
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6s, 9.3"
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6-Plus, 9.3"
```

**Important** Quit the simulator before launching a different target simulator (On Menu bar select `Simulator->Quit`)

Take into account that you may need to quit the iOS simulator via menu to switch from 3.5 to 4 inch iPhone.

dynamic list is available in `platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images`

Comment: Thanks, this helped. What was your source for this? Just wondering how I could have figured this out myself...

The answer to this question also helped a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877840/simulate-ipad-using-cordova-phonegap-emulator-command?rq=1

Apparently 'cordova emulate' is a wrapper voor ios-sim, which you can also talk to directly. This is what I ended up doing, so I can build & launch my code directly from my IDE of choice.

Comment: I just ran this command and can confirm the 4.7 and 5.5 inch emulators are not listed, even with Xcode 6 installed :-(

Comment: Hi, I tried this command "./platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images" but I didn't see all options,, NO iPhone 6,NO iPhone 6-Plus, NO iPad-Air 
what would be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: also don't see 6 there even after remove/add platform again using cordova 4.0.0

Comment: I don't really know why but for me Cordova CLI would throw `"Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"` when specifying the target with quotes, I could only get it to work by running it like this `cordova run ios --target=iPhone-6`. Hope this saves someone else some trouble!

Comment: I'm having the same problematic result as Gifford N.  I'm using cordova 7.0.0

Comment: Thanks @GiffordN. It sure did save me some trouble!

Answer (score 21):

As say [csantanapr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721344/csantanapr) you can use:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-4s"
```

but, in this case cordova (or PhoneGap or other) project will be launched on **iPhone 4s simulator with iOS version 7.0.3**.

If you want launch project on same simulator, but with other version iOS (7.1 or 8.0, if it versions exist in your system)?

Of corse, you can do like say [cobberboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956779/cobberboy):

> start a specific emulator and choose your ios version by directly using ios-sim.

But you can improve `--target` option of cordova `run` command.

**At first you must ensure what target iOS version available on your system.**

For it use answer of [cobberboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956779/cobberboy):

```
$ ios-sim showdevicetypes
```

Then you need to open the file `your_project_dir/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js` and find lines of code like below:

```
// validate target device for ios-sim
// Valid values for "--target" (case sensitive):
var validTargets = ['iPhone-4s', 'iPhone-5', 'iPhone-5s', 'iPhone-6-Plus', 'iPhone-6',
    'iPad-2', 'iPad-Retina', 'iPad-Air', 'Resizable-iPhone', 'Resizable-iPad'];
```

For use `iPhone-4s, 7.1` (or some other) simple add it to array `validTargets`.

```
var validTargets = ['iPhone-4s', 'iPhone-4s, 7.1', 'iPhone-5', 'iPhone-5s', 'iPhone-6-Plus', 'iPhone-6',
    'iPad-2', 'iPad-Retina', 'iPad-Air', 'Resizable-iPhone', 'Resizable-iPad'];
```

And in

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-4s, 7.1"
```

your `--target="iPhone-4s, 7.1"` will be valid.

And function `deployToSim` of `run.js`:

```
function deployToSim(appPath, target) {
// Select target device for emulator. Default is 'iPhone-6'
if (!target) {
    target = 'iPhone-6';
    console.log('No target specified for emulator. Deploying to ' + target + ' simulator');
}
var logPath = path.join(cordovaPath, 'console.log');
var simArgs = ['launch', appPath,
    '--devicetypeid', 'com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.' + target,
    // We need to redirect simulator output here to use cordova/log command
    // TODO: Is there any other way to get emulator's output to use in log command?
    '--stderr', logPath, '--stdout', logPath,
    '--exit'];
return spawn('ios-sim', simArgs);
}
```

convert `iPhone-4s, 7.1` to valid argument `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 7.1` for `ios-sim`.

Comment: This works perfectly and allowed me to use `ionic run ios --target='iPhone-6, 9.0'` when using Ionic Framework.

Comment: Good find . I simply commented out the block that validates `validTargets` and I was able to specify the full platform, ex: `"--target="iPhone-6, 8.4""`. Would be really nice if Cordova delegated target validation to `ios-sim`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I typed garbage in run.js and it was ignored. Does npm cache this or something? How can I refresh npm's cache?

Comment: You can also run "ionic platform update ios" and you will be able to run the recently installed emulators

Answer (score 11):

#### TL;DR

You can start a specific emulator and choose your ios version by directly using ios-sim.

```
export appname="./platforms/ios/build/emulator/Hello World.app"
ios-sim launch "$appname" --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2, 8.0" --stderr ./platforms/ios/cordova/console.log --stdout ./platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

#### Details

When I ran this:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPad"
```

and looked at the processes running, I saw this (on a single line):

```
ios-sim launch ./platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloWorld.app 
        --stderr ./platforms/ios/cordova/console.log 
        --stdout ./platforms/ios/cordova/console.log 
        --family ipad 
        --exit
```

Investigating further into [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim), it looks like there are some more specific options, particularly:

```
--devicetypeid <device type>    The id of the device type that should be simulated (Xcode6+). Use 'showdevicetypes' to list devices.
  e.g "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone6, 8.0"
```

So I did as it suggested and ran ios-sim with a "showdevicetypes" argument and got this:

```
$ ios-sim showdevicetypes
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air, 7.1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad, 8.0
```

Comment: How does this work for changing the default simulator? You're bypassing the cordova bit here and just launching directly, right?

Answer (score 7):

Don't include version number

```
cordova run ios --target="iPhone-6s"
```

Answer (score 4):

#### As of Xcode 8.3.2...

Old thread, I know, but it seems, perhaps, that the answer has changed slightly.  The hints from earlier posts in this thread helped, but so did reading the documentation included in the code, `<cordova-project>/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js`

Execute `./platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images` to list the available emulator images.  Do not include the version number on the end when making the cordova call to run in the desired emulator.

```
cordova run ios --emulator --target="iPad-Air"
```

[See more](https://gist.github.com/dcvezzani/ef6f44be2785c90a016fa18893a06a31)

Comment: thank god for your comment! It didn't work after the latest update and couldn't find any info. Just got the error message: "Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" which was fixed after NOT including the ios version.

Comment: @MarcoRinck check the comment on answer, there is quick fix by typing: `cordova run ios --target=iPhone-6`

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on the answer above due to my low reputation, but the list of targets is available from:

```
start-emulator
```

under

```
your platform/ios/cordova/lib/
```

Having said that, I cannot make the ipad retina emulator work...

Answer (score 3):

fastest output of devices list:
`$ instruments -s devices`

Just use the device name without the version.

Answer (score 2):

Now is:

```
cordova run ios --list
Available ios devices:
Available ios virtual devices:
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 14.3
Apple-TV-4K-4K, tvOS 14.3
Apple-TV-4K-1080p, tvOS 14.3
Apple-Watch-Series-5-40mm, watchOS 7.2
Apple-Watch-Series-5-44mm, watchOS 7.2
Apple-Watch-Series-6-40mm, watchOS 7.2
Apple-Watch-Series-6-44mm, watchOS 7.2
iPhone-8, 14.3
iPhone-8-Plus, 14.3
iPhone-11, 14.3
iPhone-11-Pro, 14.3
iPhone-11-Pro-Max, 14.3
iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-, 14.3
iPhone-12-mini, 14.3
iPhone-12, 14.3
iPhone-12-Pro, 14.3
iPhone-12-Pro-Max, 14.3
iPod-touch--7th-generation-, 14.3
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 14.3
iPad-Pro--11-inch---2nd-generation-, 14.3
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---4th-generation-, 14.3
iPad--8th-generation-, 14.3
iPad-Air--4th-generation-, 14.3
```

And:

```
cordova run ios --target="iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---4th-generation-, 14.3"
```

In Cordova 10.0.0

Answer (score 1):

**Different iphone and ipad simulator**

1. cordova run ios --list
2. cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-7"

Answer (score 0):

Runs iOS simulator with web request based on already generated build for cordova application. 
Execute this request from browser opens simulator on mac with iPhone 8Plus version:
http://hostname:3000/cordova/build/[xxxx-buildnumber]/emulate?target=iPhone-8-Plus

Answer (score -1):

@Birja's answer is working right now but the run command he used finally is still wrong so here the right answer:

To list all the devices available in simulator `cordova run ios --list`

It will result in something like this:

```
Available ios devices:
Available ios virtual devices:
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 12.2
Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 5.2
iPhone-5s, 12.2
iPhone-6, 12.2
iPad-Air-2, 12.2
iPad--5th-generation-, 12.2
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 12.2
iPad-Pro, 12.2
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-, 12.2
iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-, 12.2
iPad--6th-generation-, 12.2
iPad-Pro--11-inch-, 12.2
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---3rd-generation-, 12.2
```

`cordova run ios --target "iPad-Pro, 12.2"` Use any target from the above. To run in simulator.