# cordova / phonegap emulator ios specify device type and SDK version

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

Is there a way to specify the SDK / emulator type used when launching cordova run [I assume it is the same with phonegap] ?

I am using MAC OS X 10.9 with cordova 3.4.1 with IOS 6.1 and 7.0. When I launch `cordova run` from the command line:

```
Running command: /Users/username/Desktop/sharing/my_app/platforms/ios/cordova/run 
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/user/Desktop/sharing/my_app/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0
    VALID_ARCHS = i386
```

It seems that is always launching the latest sdk version. It also select the iPhone Retina device automatically.

Is there command line to specify both SDK to use and the device type ? [e.g. start the iPhone instead the the iPhone retina]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310526/cordova-start-specific-ios-emulator-image

Comment: Thank you that helped. I had to customize the scrip to also pass the SDK. it seems that the emulate script is taking by default the most recent SDK installed.