# How to update your iOS app using Cordova without supporting arm64 or having iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, armv7, arm64

I'm developing an iOS app using cordova on ARMV7 architecture because I'm using a couple of plugins that doesn't support ARM64 yet.

The problem that I can't upload the update, because iTunesConnect asks me to upload 4.7-inch and 5.5-inch which are iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. And at same time, I can't run my app on iPhone 6 simulator on Xcode because it must supports ARM64 to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, use the power of Cordova command line tools, run the simulator, save your images and then upload them to iTunesConnect.

Here's how to use Cordova command line tools
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22329264/183982

Also, make sure if you are trying to test on iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6-plus, Xcode won't work because your app must support ARM64, so make sure to disconnect your mobile phone if it is iPhone 5s or newer.