# How to change iOS-version in XCode simulator?

Tags: ios, gruntjs, ios-simulator, xcode7, emulation

I took over a mobile app project using Cordova, Ionic and AngularJS.

When sending code to emulator by i.e. running `grunt run:ios --target="iPhone-5"`, I see the latest iOS version (9.2) popping up.

Where in the XCode simulator I can change my target device ***and*** the iOS version? I know where to change the device, but not the iOS version...

Comment: Looks, I have found it myself as in XCode preferences I see such a download section.

Comment: This question has been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705666/1979489